# which devices on network use CSMA/CD

Tags: ethernet, network

CSMA/CD 's definition based on wikipedia is :

> Carrier Sense Multiple Access With Collision Detection (CSMA/CD) is a media access control method used most notably in local area networking using early Ethernet technology. It uses a carrier sensing scheme in which a transmitting data station detects other signals while transmitting a frame, and stops transmitting that frame, transmits a jam signal, and then waits for a random time interval before trying to resend the frame.

1. I know about this algorithm. But what I am looking for is which devices on computer networking field use this algorithm to access the medium?
2. Is switch use CSMA/CD algorithm to deal with collision on wired media ?

Comment: I believe this died with very early implementations of 10Gbit Ethernet, as it's a very inefficient and inconsistent algorithm to deal with collisions. Can you rephrase your second quesion?

Comment: On my text books, I read about CSMA/CD, so they died for long time, what is alternative algorithm for them?

Comment: @user36129, I think you mean 2 Mb/s and 10 Mb/s ethernet.

Comment: @alex, more recent ethernet isn't multidrop, just point-to-point, so CSMA/CD isn't needed.

Comment: @ThePhoton: whoops... yeah, megabits, not gigabit :P Will Dean has his facts straight, that's exactly how I remember it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the first part of your question is not much nowadays, if we're talking about wired networks.

10Base-2 and 10Base-5 Ethernet were based on coaxial cable, with a shared medium (everybody talked and listened on the same wire), so used CSMA/CD.

10Base-T originally used 'hubs' which were just signal amplifiers/conditioners, and everybody on the network still used the same collision domain so needed the same rules, although at least the physical medium was separated and a fault on one connection didn't bring the whole network down.

Then the cost of switched Ethernet became low enough that hubs were pretty much universally replaced by switches - with a switch there is not one shared network or collision domain, but instead there's effectively *one network per connected machine*.  Each of these little networks has just two devices on it - the connected computer and the switch port.

The switch then forwards packets from one mini-network to another, based on the destination address and an address table it builds-up in RAM.

So there is no concept of a collision at all, because there are only two devices on the network and they have a separate receive and transmit wires to talk on, so never interrupt each other.